# How To Use PHP Variable Into jQuery .load() Script?

Tags: php, jquery

I have this jQuery script with `.load()` function and this script saved on file named `header.php`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my-wrapper').find(".wrapper-area").append('<div class="loadergif"></div>').load("file001.php?key=XXXXXX", function() {
    $(this).find('.wrapper-area').remove('.loadergif');
    var $container = $('.list-wrap');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.my-wrapper'
        });
    });
});
```

on the other side, I have this PHP variables on file named body.php :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $Key = $row['key'];
    echo '<div class="wrapper-area">';
       //jQuery script will produce something here             
    echo '</div><!-- .wrapper-area -->';
}
```

now the problem is how to bring that $Key from PHP file becomes XXXXXX part of jQuery script : '`file001.php?key=XXXXXX`'

please note that $Key is dynamically generated from WHILE loop. means, it has different value each loop cycle.

thanks before

Comment: Add that id as an attribute of the div, you can then access it from javascript via that attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, replace your following line:

```
echo '<div class="wrapper-area">';
```

for this one:

```
echo '<div class="wrapper-area" data-key="'.$Key.'">';
```

In jQuery, replace your following line:

```
$('.my-wrapper').find(".wrapper-area").append('<div class="loadergif"></div>').load("file001.php?key=XXXXXX", function() {
```

for this one:

```
$('.my-wrapper').find(".wrapper-area").each(function() {
   $(this).append('<div class="loadergif"></div>').load("file001.php?key"+$(this).data('key'), function() {
    ...
    ...
}); //close the each() call
}); //close document.ready()
```

Comment: I got perfectly $Key from first loop, but the second loop until the rest of it are same with $Key from first loop.

Comment: Yes it had a bug, I've updated my answer with a fix for jquery code, try it.

Comment: what the last .load used for? isn't that enough using just .load("file001.php?key"+$(this).data('key') on the first part?

Comment: it works...! doesn't need to have this line : .load("file001.php?key="+$('.my-wrapper').find(".wrapper-area")., function() {

Comment: Yes, that line was left by error. I'm glad this worked for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear but I think that you want to change your load line to this -

```
.load("file001.php", {key:XXXXXX}, function() {
```

Comment: I just want to make .load part becomes like this : .load("file001.php?key=$Key") which $Key is generated by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to build the wrappers:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

  echo '<div class="wrapper-area" data-key="' . $row['key'] . '">';

  // ...

}
```

And this for the jQuery:

```
$(function()
{

  $('.my-wrapper').find('.wrapper_area').each(function()
  {

    $(this).append('<div class="loadergif"></div>').load('file001.php?key=' + $(this).attr('data-key'), function()
    {
      // ...
    }
    )

  }
  )

}
)
```

Comment: I got 'undefined' as an output of your : + $(this).attr('data-key') when I tried to echo the variable of $_GET['key']

Comment: View the source. What is in the `data-key` attribute of the `.wrapper_area divs`?

Comment: I see dynamic data-key exactly as I expected from WHILE loop. but I think there's something missing here : .load('file001.php?key='+$(this).attr('data-key'), so when I try to GET the variable : $_GET['key'] I got 'undefined' as an output.

Comment: I mean, I see dynamic data-key exactly as I expected from WHILE loop on each DIVs